# Настройка даты и времени в input

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как сделать, чтобы `<input  type="datetime-local" >` имел максимальное значение даты и времени, сегодня. Через JS.

Нужно, чтобы при выборе даты и времени пользователем было ограничение до сегодняшнего дня и времени открытия модального окна.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Пожалуйста, раскройте вашу мысль.

Comment: Нужно чтобы при выборе даты и времени пользователем было ограничение до сегодняшнего дня и времени открытия модального окна. То есть открывается модальное окно и там выбор даты и времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чисто для даты используйте `date`:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // Месяца идут с 0, так что добавляем 1.
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd < 10){
  dd='0' + dd
} 
if(mm < 10){
  mm='0' + mm
} 

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById("datetime-local").setAttribute("max", today);
```

```html
<input id="datetime-local" type="date"></input>
```

Если нужно ещё и время, тогда можно вот так:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // Месяца идут с 0, так что добавляем 1.
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var minutes = today.getMinutes();
var hour = today.getHours();
if(dd < 10){
  dd='0' + dd
} 
if(mm < 10){
  mm='0' + mm
}
if(hour < 10){
  hour='0' + hour
}
if(minutes < 10){
  minutes='0' + minutes
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + 'T' + hour + ':' + minutes;
document.getElementById("datetime-local").setAttribute("max", today);
```

```html
<input id="datetime-local" type="datetime-local"></input>
```

Comment: Это работает только если мышкой кликать. Вручную с клавиатуры можно вбить любую дату.

Comment: Согласен, тогда бы я ставил пакет для работы с datetime, но тут нужно уточнить автору, что конкретно ему нужно.

Comment: Чтобы было ограничение как в вашем коде, только с добавлением времени, или проще будет использовать этот и добавить рядом новое поле времени?

Comment: @WINDRIA добавил в ответ код где и проверка времени есть, но на сервере всё равно лучше проверять.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    id="meeting-time"
    name="meeting-time"
    value="2018-06-12T19:30"
    min="2018-06-07T00:00"
    max="2018-06-14T00:00">
```

1. value - формат который ты установил как базовое значение
2. min - минимальная дата
3. max - максимальная дата которая может быть установленна пользователем

   ссылка на больше информации:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local](http://%3Cinput%20%20%20%20%20type=%22datetime-local%22%20%20%20%20%20id=%22meeting-time%22%20%20%20%20%20name=%22meeting-time%22%20%20%20%20%20value=%222018-06-12T19:30%22%20%20%20%20%20min=%222018-06-07T00:00%22%20%20%20%20%20max=%222018-06-14T00:00%22%3E%20%20%20%20%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%20%20value%20-%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%20%20min%20-%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20%20%20max%20-%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%20%20%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local%22%3Ehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local%3C/a%3E)

Comment: Нужно автоматическое ограничение ввода даты